# Global variable inside Spinner onItemSelected does not work

Tags: android, global-variables, spinner, onitemselectedlistener

I've been thinking about this a long while but realy can't figure out what the problem is. The first code piece works in one of my activities. selectedUser is globally declarend and I can use it everywhere.

```
        spUsers.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.user_sp_row,userArray));
    spUsers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            int index = spUsers.getSelectedItemPosition();
            selectedUser = userList.get(index).get(Constants.TAG_UNAME);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            selectedUser = "";
        }

    });
```

This code does not work allthough it looks the same like the other code I wrote. selectedCat is also globally declared. The thing is the value is set in the onItemSelected method but as soon as it leaves the method selectedCat is an empty string.

```
        spCat.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.category_sp_row,tempArray));
    spCat.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            int index = spCat.getSelectedItemPosition();
            selectedCat = categoryList.get(index).get(Constants.TAG_UPID);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            selectedCat = "";
        }

    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "soon as it leaves the method" what are you trying to do with selectedCat ?

Comment: When i put bt91.setText(selectedCat); in the onItemSelected method it shows the text that selectedCat should contain but when I put it after the }); or anywhere else in my code it does not work it shows no text.

Comment: get rid of the  selectedCat = ""; and see if that makes a difference ?

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. I just had a look at the spinner I have implements in my apps and I am just doing all I need to do with the selected item inside the onItemSelected method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this working by indeed doing everything that needs to be done in the setOnItemSelectedListener().

Ty DrkStr

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why are using `int index = spUsers.getSelectedItemPosition();` to get the index when you can use the position integer provided in `onItemSelected()` method.

Comment: That's indeed true but I was just juggling around to get this working :)